# Redrawing images using Kinetic JS Framework

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

## Outline

My question involves the use of KineticJS, but before I'll ask the question - I'll outline the project and then discuss my problem.

### The Task

My task is create a resizing fireplace surround so that said individual can use a number form to change the size of the surround, the only pieces that should actually change are it's Jambs (legs either side) in their Height and the mantel across the top.

Now the surround needs to be made from images, so it's been broken down into seperate elements so when the width of the image is stretched the whole surround isn't.

I've created the canvas and referenced KineticJs the framework I'm using for this project to benefit from it's easy to use layer and stage design similar to that of Adobe Flash.

### The Issue

My problem occurs after loading all the images required. I've used abit of JQUERY to call the function to draw the surround and load it's seperate parts once the document is ready.

Once there I have a change event function ready to resize the surround once the user interacts with the number form.

Issue is all of the surround variables are contained in a function called drawsomething()

Now they're local to that function I require them in another.

I'm aware i'll probably have to restructure my code to get this to work. I'm just not entirely sure where to begin.

Could anyone begin by pointing me in the correct direction?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Canvas Project Two</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kinetic-v4.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    drawSomething();
    $("#slider").change(function(){
        
        redraw();
        
        });
    
    
    })

    


    function drawSomething(){

    
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var leftMantel = new Image();
    var rightMantel = new Image();
    var leftJamb = new Image();
    var rightJamb = new Image();
    var leftFoot = new Image();
    var rightFoot =  new Image();   
    
        imageObj.src = "octon_mantel.png";
    
    imageObj.onload = function(){
    

    
    var image = new Kinetic.Image
        ({
            x:450,
            y:150,
            width:280,
            height:117,
            image: imageObj
        });

            layer.add(image);
            layer.draw();
}
            
    

    leftMantel.onload = function(){
    var LeftMant = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:300,
            y:150,
            width:150,
            height:117,
            image: leftMantel
            
        
        }); 
        
        layer.add(LeftMant);
        layer.draw();
    }
        
        
    rightMantel.onload = function(){
    var RightMant = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:730,
            y:150,
            width:150,
            height:117,
            image: rightMantel
            
        
        });
        
        layer.add(RightMant);
        layer.draw();
            }
        
        


    rightJamb.onload = function(){      
    var RightJamb = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:732,
            y:267,
            width:105,
            height:200,
            image: rightJamb
            
        
        });     
        
        layer.add(RightJamb);
        layer.draw();
        }
        
        
        
    rightFoot.onload = function(){  
    var RightFoot = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:732,
            y:465,
            width:104,
            height:127,
            image: rightFoot
            
        
        }); 
        
        layer.add(RightFoot);
        layer.draw();
        }
        
        
    
    
    
    leftJamb.onload = function(){
    var LeftJamb = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:343,
            y:267,
            width:105,
            height:200,
            image: leftJamb
            
        
        });
        
        layer.add(LeftJamb);
        layer.draw();
        
            }
        
        
    leftFoot.onload = function(){   
    var LeftFoot = new Kinetic.Image({
            
            x:344,
            y:465,
            width:104,
            height:127,
            image: leftFoot
            
        
        }); 
        
        layer.add(LeftFoot);
        layer.draw();
        
        }
        
    //Image Location Declaration
    imageObj.src = "octon_mantel.png";
    leftMantel.src = "octon_mantel_left.png";
    rightMantel.src = "octon_mantel_right.png";
    rightJamb.src = "octon_jamb_right.png";
    rightFoot.src = "octon_foot_right.png";
    leftJamb.src = "octon_jamb_left.png";
    leftFoot.src = "octon_foot_left.png";
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    
function redraw(){
        
        
        alert("hey");
        
        
        
        }




</script>
<style>
body {
    background-color:#fff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form style="float:left; height:600px; margin-top:30px; margin-left:30px;">
  <fieldset style="height:600px; border:solid 2px black; border-radius:10px;">
    <legend style="font-size:18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">Fireplace Surround</legend>
    <br/>
    Mantel width<br/>
    <input type="number" value="280" id="slider"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Jamb Height<br/>
    <input type="number" value="200" id="jambheightSlider"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="myCanvas"></div>
<script>

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage
({
    container: myCanvas,
    width:900,
    height: 700
    
    
});

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... you have

```
function drawSomething(){


var imageObj = new Image();
var leftMantel = new Image();
var rightMantel = new Image();
var leftJamb = new Image();
var rightJamb = new Image();
var leftFoot = new Image();
var rightFoot =  new Image();   
//.... Other stuff
}
```

and you want the scope of the variables to not be local to the function itself. Simple fix/hack:

```
var imageObj;
var leftMantel;
var rightMantel;
var leftJamb;
var rightJamb;
var leftFoot;
var rightFoot;

function drawSomething(){
   imageObj = new Image();
   leftMantel = new Image();
   rightMantel = new Image();
   leftJamb = new Image();
   rightJamb = new Image();
   leftFoot = new Image();
   rightFoot =  new Image();   
   //.... Other stuff
}
```

now your function just modifies existing variables, which are accessible outside of the function.

Comment: This quick fix helped lots, thank you. Its actually the variables inside the load functions that made the difference - the ones in my code I declare as Kinetic.Image objects.

So I declared them outside the function as you said - then made them Kinetic.Images as normal.

This made it easier to getWidth() of images from outside the function.